# VSCode adding controls to a form not working

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-code, .net-7.0

I have a win forms project set up in Visual Studio Code with Program.cs, Form1.cs etc.
I am trying to add a control to the Form1 when the window loads, but it doesn't seem to work.

This is my code:

```
public void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("form loaded!");
    //cant see this debug log in output
    //program main window launch
    Button startButton = new Button();
    startButton.Name = "startButton1";
    startButton.Click += (sender, e) => {
        //start button clicked
        MessageBox.Show("siema");
    };
    this.Controls.Add(startButton);
    startButton.Show();
    startButton.Location = new Point(0, 0);
    startButton.AutoSize = false;
    startButton.Size = new Size(80, 80);
    startButton.Text = "fuck you bitch";
    startButton.BringToFront();
    startButton.Invalidate();
    this.Refresh();
}
```

I have tried to put same code under the InitializeComponent() but no effect.

Comment: i cant see the console.writeline in the output too

Comment: why don't you EDIT your question

Comment: where to tell `Form1` to call this function on load ready

Comment: i have this line `this.Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);` Above the InitializeComponent();

Comment: Show also the code creating and showing this form.

Answer (score 0):

It appears `dotnet new winforms` creates two separate folders in bin/Debug
It built the project to Debug/net7.0-windows, while it ran the executable from Debug/net7.0/project.exe

Every time i build, i have to run the correct executable :/